# title not displayed on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the following code for a custom back button with title in the nav bar. However, the title is not being shown, any help ?

nb: the back button image is black and the same one thats used by default by ios, needed to customize the action handler, thats why did it this way.

```
backButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];    
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,64,32)];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[backButton setTitle:@"Encameo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"Encameo" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
```

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681321/uibarbuttonitem-with-custom-image-and-no-border/2681430#2681430

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting image on button instead of this you need to set backgroundImage of UIButton then your title will be displayed.

Change the code like this

```
backButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];    
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,64,32)];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[backButton setTitle:@"Encameo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"Encameo" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
```

Comment: If you are using the same title color and title for both normal and selected states, it's enough if you declare for normal